# Empty response from facebook graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

On the site i have a several groups - https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3rVBfRM-EoccDYzQ2phMjZOZ1k&authuser=0 .
But facebook api return me empty response:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/me/groups?access_token=...
{
   "data": [

   ]
}
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the user_groups permission in order to see a list of groups you are in.  Facebook will probably not allow you to use that permission in a production app.

From https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3

> Limited Use
>   This permission is granted to apps building a Facebook-branded client on platforms where Facebook is not already available. For example, Android and iOS apps will not be approved for this permission. In addition, Web, Desktop, in-car and TV apps will not be granted this permission.